# How to Make ip point to stack segment in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, stack-overflow

IN SHORT: I want to run a code that is in the stack segment.

PROBLEM IN DETAILS:
our assigment is to make an attacking program using the stack overflow method.

the program prints out a code to file1.txt
the target program has a PROC that allocates space and gets characters into the allocated stack .

we want the target program to get the attacking code from file1.txt , 
and force it to run the code from the stack.
now, we need the return value of the PROC to be exchanged with the address of the attacking code that is in the stack segment.

I succeeded to exchange the ret value of the PROC with the address of the code, BUT, the ip thinks that this effective address is of the CODE SEGMENT instead of the STACK SEGMENT.

SO, how do we make the ip know that this address of the STACK SEGMENT and not of the CODE SEGMENT ???

Comment: You forgot to mention what OS and what architecture. Typical operating systems nowadays use flat memory, so there is no code or stack segment.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are speaking on a memory model that distinguishes `code` and `stack` **segments** at least by their actual location in a physical `RAM` and that the code is running in [real 8086 mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_mode) (otherwise you hardly would determine the correct value of a segment descriptor that matches the stack segment's address space and allows the code execution during attack ) you have three options: `far call`, `far jump` and `far ret` instructions. See some Intel x86 instruction set reference for definitions of these instructions, for example [this one](http://www.intel.ru/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf)